# Version number does not appear in package.json

Tags: npm

I type `npm install slugify` in the console. But in package.json it appears as

```
"dependencies": { 
    "slugify": "*" 
}
```

The version number appears as * where it should be. Why doesn't the version number appear?

I tried typing `npm install slugify` and waited for the version number to appear in the package.json file.

Comment: When I type npm install asdfafsaf, it happens like this:
"dependencies": {
     "asdfafsaf ": "*"
}

Actually the package is available here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/slugify

Comment: Since your question is not related to any PowerShell code, could you please remove the `PowerShell` tag? Thanks in advance. 

Comment: npm packages use Semantic Versioning to specify versions. *You* decide what version you want to use. You specified no version when you installed it, so it provided no version in package.json. If you specify a version (by using `npm install slugify@1.6.6` or `npm install slugify@latest`) then it will provide a version in package.json. Most packages, when first installed, provide the latest version number to put in package.json, but it is by no means required.